# AWS instance cloning using CPP SDK

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I know that we can clone an existing instance of AWS using Management console.But is it possible to clone an instance using CPP SDK.I didn't find any examples related to cloning of instance.